# What is the URL to access a Hello-World Google Cloud Endpoint service?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've generated a Google Endpoint AppEngine project in  Eclipse by using the `Generate AppEngine BackEnd` as described in [this blog post](http://devthots.blogspot.no/2012/07/building-awesome-android-apps-with.html). What that post does *not* describe however, and which the official Google Docs describe poorly as well, is which URL I can access that service with locally?

The service generated has one generated endpoint called DeviceInfoEndpoint. The code is shown below as well as the code in web.xml. Which URL should I access listDeviceInfo() with given that I'm hosting on port 8888 locally? I've tried the following:

- `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/listDeviceInfo` => 404
- `http://localhost:8888/_ah/spi/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/listDeviceInfo` => 405 GET not supported
- `http://localhost:8888/_ah/spi/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/DeviceInfo` => 405 GET (...)
- `http://localhost:8888/_ah/spi/v1/deviceinfoendpoint/listDeviceInfo` = > 405 GET(...)

Exerpt of DeviceInfoEndpoint.java:

```
@Api(name = "deviceinfoendpoint")
public class DeviceInfoEndpoint {

/**
 * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
 * It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @return List of all entities persisted.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "cast", "unchecked" })
public List<DeviceInfo> listDeviceInfo() {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    List<DeviceInfo> result = new ArrayList<DeviceInfo>();
    try {
        Query query = mgr
                .createQuery("select from DeviceInfo as DeviceInfo");
        for (Object obj : (List<Object>) query.getResultList()) {
            result.add(((DeviceInfo) obj));
        }
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value>com.example.dummyandroidapp.DeviceInfoEndpoint</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

API request paths should generally conform to the following:

```
http(s)://{API_HOST}:{PORT}/_ah/api/{API_NAME}/{VERSION}/
```

If you're interested in fetching/updating/deleting a specific resource, add an ID to the end. In your example, that suggests you should be querying:

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/
```

(which maps to `list` when you're making a `GET` request).

In general, the APIs Explorer available at `/_ah/_api/explorer` makes it easy to discover and query these URLs.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me on the way. I've spent the day digging into the method-naming convention and ended up writing a blog post which summarizes this and more: http://www.nilzorblog.com/2013/02/a-google-cloud-endpoints-hello-world.html

Comment: Just to give a concrete answer to my case - the correct URL is `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/deviceinfo`

Answer (score 1):

You can controle the path by use:

```
  @ApiMethod(path="listDeviceInfo",  httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public List<DeviceInfo> listDeviceInfo(){
    //... definition

  }
```

Then you can call  that from you client as: 
http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/listDeviceInfo

If  you like send parameters then:

```
@ApiMethod(path="listDeviceInfo",  httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
        public List<DeviceInfo> listDeviceInfo(@Named("info") String info){
        //... definition

  }
```

http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/deviceinfoendpoint/v1/listDeviceInfo?info=holamundo